# Controller specs when stubbing devise authentication are never invoking controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

So I'm running into a very weird issue when attempting to write some controller specs for a rails application I am working on. Basically at a high level it seems like the spec is never actually invoking the controller action. A couple of things that I've done and found..

1. After doing some looking around I attempted to see if it was possibly a routing issue and to test this I used `controller.index` and sure enough the action is invoked and the test passed. That being said this obviously leads to issues when I'm attempting to call actions that require params so I'd like to get `#get|#post` etc. working.
2. When I run `expect(response).to be_successful`and write `fail 'some message'` in the controller action the test still passes, which further proves nothing is occurring surrounding the controller action.
3. I went about preventing devise from authenticating the user by removing `before_filter :authenticate_user!` from the application_controller and then for whatever reason the spec runs and hits the action correctly and the spec passes. Now, this is occurring even when using `#get` which works against the theory of this being a routing issue.

Because of the last point I think the problem lies somewhere in how the devise auth is being handled so to touch on that the only thing in this stack that isn't straight out of the box devise-wise is a controller helper for authentication that I use before hitting protected views which is pulled directly from the devise wiki on specs. It can be see here:

```
def sign_in(user = double('user'))
  if user.nil?
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
  else
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  end
end
```

Now even though I think the issue is in devise it's probably a good idea to give examples of everything else. So let me give you a lay of the land (of course some stuff is scrubbed out and simplified):

routes.rb:

```
namespace :api, path: '', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    ..
    resources :accounts
  end
end
```

alerts_controller.rb:

```
class AlertsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @alerts = Alert.all
  end

end
```

alerts_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AlertsController, type: :controller do
  let(:user){ create :user, :admin }
  let(:alert){ create :alert }

  before do
    sign_in user
  end

  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'responds successfully' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:alerts)).to eq [alert]
    end
   end
end
```

`rake routes => GET /v1/alerts(.:format) api/v1/alerts#index {:subdomain=>"api"}`

Any help would be highly appreciated as I'm seriously stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue and honestly it was pretty stupid and my own fault :P. In my application controller there is a `use_user_timezone` around filter. The around filter was only added to callbacks if there was a current_user. Earlier on, for some reason, I prevented the code in the around filter from running unless `Rails.env.test? == true`. Obviously I didn't really have any reason for writing this code.. The problem was that I was not preventing the *around_filter* from running if it was the test environment, but that I was preventing *the code in the filter method* from running if it was the test environment. Because of this I was not yielding to any code to execute for the around filter, which was of course causing the issue with the controller action never executing.

The reason that devise was seeming to play an issue in the mix was because the around filter executing was dependent on a `current_user` being present. Due to this the controller flow was continuing on with no problem when no auth was occurring since there was no `current_user`.

The wrap this up.. As always it's best to be attentive when making changes like this to a codebase as little bugs like this can cause major headaches later on down the road :).

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own helper for that. Devise comes with a helper just for this

Include it for your specs like this

```
#spec/rails_helper.rb
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

And then use it. In your case all you need to do is change this

```
before do
  sign_in user
end
```

to this

```
before do
  sign_in :user, user
end
```

Comment: Ah, good call on just using devise's helper ;). Unfortunately this didn't make any difference though :(

Comment: interesting. try using admin_user instead of user. like this ```sign_in :admin_user, user```